# Conditionally bind ViewModel to Tree panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

We have build a managementment system in extjs, in this system we have a dialog which makes it possible to select multiple pages, save the selection which closes the dialog.

[image]

We have reused the same component 'Ext.Tree.Panel' for a single select page, this tree should not have checkboxes and immediately save and close the dialog on itemClick. We have both trees working... but not at the same time.

We did create two separate ViewModels for both trees. Would it be possible to change the ViewModel based a property of the parent Store.

Or are we pursuing the wrong direction and is there a better alternative to use the same Tree component with different behaviour. Thx & See the code of the elements in place below

Selecttree.js

```
Ext.define('EurocampingsCMS.view.page.SelectTree', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.page-select-tree',
requires: [
    'EurocampingsCMS.controller.page.SelectTree',
    'EurocampingsCMS.view.page.MultiSelectViewModel',
    'EurocampingsCMS.view.page.SingleSelectViewModel'
],
controller: 'page-select-tree',
viewModel: 'page.select',
loadMask: true,
rootVisible: false,
overflowY: true,
config: {
    rootId: null,
},
title: 'Pagina\'s',
hideHeaders: true,
animCollapse: true,
enableSort: false,
collapseFirst: false,
multiSelect: false,
border: 0,
listeners: {
    itemclick: 'onItemClick',
    afterrender: 'onGridAfterRender',
    reconfigure: 'onGridReconfigure'
},
bind: {
    store: '{pages}'
},
columns: [
    {
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 2,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            selectOnFocus: true
        },
        renderer:  function(value, metaData, list, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
            if (!list.get('active')) {
                return '<span class="inactive">' + value + '</span>';
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
]
```

});

MultiSelectViewModel.js

```
Ext.define('EurocampingsCMS.view.page.MultiSelectViewModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.page.select',
requires: [
    'EurocampingsCMS.store.page.Select',
    'EurocampingsCMS.view.ViewModel'
],
config: {
    singleSelect: false,
},
stores: {
    pages: {
        type: 'page.select',
        autoLoad: true,
        checkedItems: '{checkedItems}',
        proxy: {
            extraParams: {
                locale: '{current.locale}'
            }
        },
    },
}
```

});

SingleSelectViewModel.js

```
Ext.define('EurocampingsCMS.view.page.SingleSelectViewModel', {
extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
alias: 'viewmodel.page.page',
requires: [
    'EurocampingsCMS.store.page.Select',
    'EurocampingsCMS.view.ViewModel'
],
config: {
    singleSelect: true,
},
stores: {
    pages: {
        type: 'page',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            extraParams: {
                locale: '{current.locale}'
            }
        }
    },
}
```

});